# Distribucion en flexbox

Tags: html, css

Necesito crear la distribucion como se ve la imagen pero no logro realizar ese diseño. Realicé un diseño con html y css peor no los logro ajustar como en la imagen. Favor su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que haz intentado hacer? por favor vuelve a editar la pregunta e introduce el código que fuiste haciendo para poder ayudarte entre todos!

Comment: Pon el código que tienes para ver en que te ayudamos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que comentas es complicado de hacer con flexbox. Flexbox ayuda a organizar los componentes de manera relativa, y lo cierto es que es fantástico, pero lo que comentas sería mucho más fácil realizarlo con el grid system de css o el de bootstrap.

Yo lo he realizado con bootstrap, te adjunto el código con el resutlado. Espero que te sirva o por lo menos te hagas una idea de como va.

https://codepen.io/EmilioVM/full/PoerGqO

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- lado izquierdo -->
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-primary">
                        <p>bienvenido...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 bg-success">
                        <p>imagen</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
                                <p>productos</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 bg-danger">
                                <p>imagen</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-primary">
                        <p>reservar clase</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- lado derecho -->
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
                        <p>horario...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 bg-primary">
                                <p>resultado juego</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 bg-secondary">
                                <p>entrada...</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 bg-success">
                        <p>imagen</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-info">
                        <p>estamos ubicados...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```